# Rails, Is there a way to generate Unit Tests from Existing Controllers and methods defined in them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I was wondering if there is a script that can take existing codebase and generate unit tests for each method in controllers. By default all would be passing since they would be empty and i can remove tests i for methods i dont feel important.

This would save huge time and increase testing. Since i'd have to define only what each method should output and not boilerplate that needs to be written.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't be doing this. Creating pointless tests is technical debt that you don't want. Take some time, go through each controller and write a test (or preferably a few) for each method. You'll thank yourself in the long run.

You can then also use test coverage tools to see which bits still need testing.

You can use shared tests to avoid repetition. So for example with rspec, you could add the following to your spec_helper/rails_helper

```
def should_be_ok(action)
  it "should respond with ok" do
    get action.to_sym
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

Then in your controller_spec

```
describe UserController do
  should_be_ok(:index)
  should_be_ok(:new)
end
```

Comment: i want to create tests for all methods but they wont test anything and i'd delete most test. While this is creative, my aim was to not write boilerplate code on my own.